# can you update a model instance without calling save( )?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I am working on a project that requires unique slugs. The slugs are dynamically created in a custom save() method using the objects name.

```
class SlugMixin(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = striptags(self.name)
        self.slug = slugify(slug)
        super(SlugMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

name is not unique so it's possible to have multiples of the same slug. So the solution i was working with is appending the id of the instance to it's slug in a post_save. The problem here is by attempting to update the slug with the id. save() needs to be called again.

```
def ensure_unique_slug(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and Person.objects.filter(slug=instance.slug).count() > 1:
        instance.slug = instance.slug + '-{}'.format(instance.id)
        instance.save()
```

rendering the update useless. is there anyway to update the slug without calling save()

Comment: Yes, you can use `.update(..)`.

Comment: i believe this only works with a queryset. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: correct, but you can use a `QuerySet`, like `Person.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(foo=bar)`.

Comment: If you don't really need to save the slug in database, you can create a `slug` property on your model which will dynamically return `slugify(name + id)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks that worked well!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use update method to prevent update all fields of model with save method, you can use `update_fields` argument in the `save()`.
it will update just needed fields:

```py
instance.field1='some value'
instance.field2='some other value'
instance.save(update_fields=['field1','field2'])
```